# How do you apply allow-stretch to all sitecore media img tags?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, image-resizing, sitecore-media-library

How do I make it so that the "allow-stretch" property is applied to all of the  tags that sitecore creates when inserting media from the media library?

I understand that you can set the allow-stretch property using the individual `<sc:image>` tags, but I want this setting to be applied globally so that whenever a user inserts media from the media library onto the page, the generated  tag already has the "as=1" property applied to it by default.

Currently, whenever a user inserts media from the media library in my web application, the image tag created by sitecore looks something like this:

```
<img alt="" height="500" width="709" src="~/media/EAF03CA5568245B59FDDCC4B8FBD83E4.ashx?h=500&amp;w=709" />`
```

but I want it to look something like this:

```
<img alt="" height="500" width="709" src="~/media/EAF03CA5568245B59FDDCC4B8FBD83E4.ashx?h=500&amp;w=709&as=1" />
```

Notice that the second img tag that i provided has as=1 at the end.

Does anyone know how to make this happen?

I'm using Sitecore 6.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own implementation of `MediaProvider` and set `AllowStretch` to always true. Inherit from `Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaProvider` and override the `GetMediaUrl()` method:

```
namespace MyCustom.Media
{
  public class MediaProvider : Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaProvider
  {
    public override string GetMediaUrl(MediaItem item)
    {
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) item, "item");
      return this.GetMediaUrl(item, MediaUrlOptions.Empty);
    }

    public override string GetMediaUrl(MediaItem item, MediaUrlOptions options)
    {
      options.AllowStretch = true;
      return base.GetMediaUrl(item, options);
    }
}
```

And then in config patch the media provider to your custom implementation:

```
<mediaProvider type="MyCustom.Media.MediaProvider, MyCustom.Kernel"/>
```

EDIT: As Maras has suggested, try overriding the overloaded `GetMediaUrl(MediaItem item, MediaUrlOptions options)` method too.

Comment: I replaced the existing mediaProvider in the config with my new one and created my own implementation of the media provider but it didn't change anything. What else could I be missing? the Img tags still don't have as=1...

Comment: I suppose you should override `public virtual string GetMediaUrl(MediaItem item, MediaUrlOptions options)` method as well and set `options.AllowStretch = true` before returning `base.GetMediaUrl'.

Comment: @MarasMusielak You were right. The method being used in my specific case is the GetMediaUrl(MediaItem item, MediaUrlOptions options), so all i had to do was override that method as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an extension method something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838425/how-to-generate-media-item-link-with-id-instead-of-path-in-sitecore/12844992#12844992) and set the AllowStretch property to true. You can also add a process in httprequestbegin pipeline and assign AllowStretch to all media files.